# Search value from JSON String in MySQL Using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, phpmyadmin

I trying to get search results from JSON String data in the MySql table in Laravel.

Here is my JSON String Data

```
{
    "Thursday": {
        "status": true,
        "start": "09:00",
        "end": "18:00"
    },
    "Sunday": {
        "status": false,
        "start": "09:00",
        "end": "18:00"
    },
    "Saturday": {
        "status": false,
        "start": "09:00",
        "end": "18:00"
    },
    "Monday": {
        "status": true,
        "start": "09:00",
        "end": "18:00"
    },
    "Friday": {
        "status": false,
        "start": "09:00",
        "end": "18:00"
    },
    "Tuesday": {
        "status": false,
        "start": "09:00",
        "end": "18:00"
    },
    "Wednesday": {
        "status": false,
        "start": "09:00",
        "end": "18:00"
    }
}
```

I want to search with this data into JSON String and if match then returns results.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "start": "09:00",
    "end": "18:00"
}
```

I try the below query using Laravel

```
$query->whereJsonContains('training_availability', [['Thursday' => ['start' => '09:00']]]);
```

but I don't want to use day in JSON, direct search from value without days.

Anyone can help with this.

Comment: It seems that `whereJsonContains` does not support pattern paths... Create stored MySQL procedure which extracts separate objects which contains provided `"key":"value"`, and use it.

Comment: Can you provide an example? @Akina

Comment: Either edit your question and remove everything which is relative to Laravel or create new question for pure SQL solution search. And specify **precise** MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
$query->whereJsonContains('training_availability->Thursday->start', '09:00');
```